# AttributeError at /api/list/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, django-rest-framework-gis

```
class StatusListSearchApi(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    ListAPIView):

    # queryset=status.objects.all()
    serializer_class=statusSerializer
    lookup_field='id'
        # return Response(serializer.datax)
    def get_queryset(self):
        request=self.request
        qs=status.objects.all()
        query=request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs=qs.filter(content__icontains=query)
        return qs

    def get_object(self):
        request=self.request
        passed_id=request.GET.get('id',None)
        queryset=self.get_queryset()
        obj=None
        if passed_id is not None:
            obj=get_object_or_404(queryset,id=passed_id)
            self.check_object_permissions(request,obj)
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        passed_id=request.GET.get('id',None)
        if passed_id is not None:
            return self.retrieve(request,*args,**kwargs)
        return super().get(request,*args,**kwargs)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.create(request,*args,**kwargs)
    def put(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.update(request,*args,**kwargs)
    def patch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.update(request,*args,**kwargs)

    def delete(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

I have tried to use the mixin serializer to serialize but when I tried to use delete in my browsable api, I got stuck with an error:

> AttributeError at /api/list/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

Creating and retrieving is working fine, but update and delete aren't working.

I don't know what the issue is....

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin` `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` `mixins.DestroyModelMixin` don't needed in `ListAPI`. You need only `ListAPIView` and `CreateAPIView`

Comment: how can you say that they dont need it, if case if want all my crud operations in a single view for a single api endpoint  ,how can i make it possible

Comment: You want `PUT` in your ListAPI to replace the entire collection with another collection? Or `DELETE` in your ListAPI to delete the entire collection? Or you want to delete or edit only single instance? I think you want `UPDATE`, `RETRIEVE` and `DELETE` only instances, not entire collection. So you need `StatusDetailSearchApi` and in this case use `RetrieveAPIView`, `DestroyAPIView`, `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`.

Comment: (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views)[http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views] look at this, there are two different views. One for LIST and another for DETAIL.

Comment: yeah i got it thanks

Comment: actually my code works it can perform the crud operations but the thing is in my get_object function i have forgot to return my obj